# Excel If Statement for different values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to evaluate a numeric column of 11 digits.
If the data starts with the first 5 digits equal to a specific numeric value, then I need to return a specific text value.  If the data starts with another specific 5 digit value, then I need to return a different text value.  I have 3 specific values to determine, but will have several more in the future

Comment: Functions to fiddle with: `LEFT` to get the first 5 digits. `INDEX` + `MATCH` to look up those first 5 in another table and return a value in the same row but another column in that lookup table. Take a whack and come back when you get stuck. Maybe you can even answer your own question.

Answer (score 2):

Make a reference table of the numbers and their string value:

[image]

Then you can use the following formula:

```
=INDEX($F$1:$F$2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$2,A1))),),0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Scott Craner's answer is works efficiently, but since you asked for a formula using IF(), I'll toss this one into the ring.

You can accomplish this by nesting `IF()` statements. The flow for `IF()` goes like this:

*`IF(`"Some comparison that evaluates to either TRUE or to FALSE,"What to do if `TRUE`", What to do if `FALSE`")*

So, you'll test for your first string and return the text value if a match is found. If the match isn't found, you run another `IF()` to look for the second. And continue that logic until you cover all conditions. So, you'll end up with this:

> =IF(VALUE(LEFT(C2,5))=$A$2,"Fours",IF(VALUE(LEFT(C2,5))=$A$3,"Threes",IF(VALUE(LEFT(C2,5))=$A$4,"Twos","No match")))

[image]

Here's a more readable version that makes the logic more apparent.

```
=IF(VALUE(LEFT(C2,5))=$A$2,
    "Fours",
    IF(VALUE(LEFT(C2,5))=$A$3,
       "Threes",
        IF(VALUE(LEFT(C2,5))=$A$4,
           "Twos",
           "No match")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vlookup, write your array like this:
First Five Digit   Value1
Second Five Digit  Value2
Third Five Digit   Value3

You can add as much as you need no limit and let us say the references of this array are $A1:$B3 it should be absolute references to fix the array.

If your Numbers are in Column C write in D the following:
**=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(VALUE(LEFT(C1,5)),$A$1:$B$3,2,FALSE),"")**